# Creating nested elements in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to replace a div with created elements, going from:

```
<div id='links'></div>
```

to

```
<div id='links'>
<ul>
<li><a href='#'>No</a></li>
</li>
</div>
```

I want to attach a function to the link in the `<a>` element that I create. Creating the desired link is working, but wrapping the link in an `<li>` element and a `<ul>` element using the wrap function isn't working:

```
var no = $('<a>').attr({
    href: '#'
  }).click(function () {
    alert('clicked no');
    return false;
  }).text('no');
```

Works, but `no.wrap('<li></li>');` still just gives me an unwrapped `<a>` element.
I've also tried `$('#links').append('<ul>').append('<li>').append(no)` but that doesn't work either.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`no.wrap('<li></li>')` will still return the `<a>` element, but it adds a `<li>` element around it. So you can do `no.wrap('<li></li>').parent()` to wrap it and return the `<li>` element.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    var list = $("<ul />");

    var no = $('<a />')
        .attr({ href: '#' })
        .click(function () {
            alert('clicked no');
            return false;
        })
        .text('no')
        .wrap("<li />")
            .parent()
            .appendTo(list);

    list.appendTo("#links");
});    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery can actually just nest everything into a wrapper, especially if you don't need to address the individual items themselves.

You can also create new elements to be nested on the fly. No need to create a bunch of temporary variables to hold them all.

Multiple items can be appended at the same time by simply passing them all as separate parameters to append().

```js
var wrapper = $('<div/>', {
  id: 'links'
});

$(wrapper).append(

  $('<ul/>').append(

    $('<li/>').append(
      $('<a/>', {
        href: '#',
        text: 'Yes'
      })
    ),

    $('<li/>').append(
      //you can even keep going! 
      $('<a/>', {
        href: '#',
        text: 'No'
      })
    ),

    $('<li/>').append(
      $('<a/>', {
        href: '#',
        text: 'Maybe'
      })
    )
  )

);
```